# CodeFirst C# Generation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, code-first

I would like to use a tool to generate C# CodeFirst Entities and Mappings. I have used Entity Framework Power Tools and am looking for a better solution.

Using Entity Framework Power Tools as an example. This allows all tables in a database to be reverse engineered with C# classes generated for each Entity and Mapping. The problem is that you have to generate them all and cannot select just a few.

Is there such a tool that can generate these C# Entities and Mappings for the tables that you select? I do not want to hand-code these C# Code First classes.

Comment: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing database you probably could use model first approach with DbContext templates. Take a look at this walkthrough http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/28/ef-4-2-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx. You can modify your model after creating it from the database. Also, when doing this this blog post may be useful too: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/02/26/dont-use-code-first-by-mistake/